# Difference between instantiating models by manager and model-name in Django

Tags: django

When I instantiate the model, I usually used the manager, e.g.

```
user = User.objects.create_objects(name='Tom', age='25')
```

but, sometime I can also see the code like,

```
user = User(name='Tom', age='25')
```

Are these two identical codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not quite... in the first case the object is immediately written in the database, in the second one it is not until you explicitly save it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you give me a hint about where I can find django codes showing the saving-the-objec- to-database part?

Comment: @Rhee if u mean an example how to save a user in your second line of code - that is simple `user.save()`

Comment: All this is rather extensively documented you know?